# How to remove an object from an array based on another array with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to edit an array of objects that I have based on another array.

For example, this is my array of objects:

```
var objs = [{ 
   attending: 0, user: '123' 
}, { 
   attending: 0, user: '456' 
}, { 
   attending: 0, user: '789' 
}];
```

And this is my array:

```
var arr = ['945', '456']
```

Since `456` exists within `arr`, I would like to remove that object from `obj`. Hence being the final result of:

```
var objs = [{ 
   attending: 0, user: '123' 
}, { 
   attending: 0, user: '789' 
}];
```

I have tried both `omit` and `pullByAll` yet had no luck:

```
var newObj = _.omit(obj, arr);
var newObj = _.pullAllBy(obj, arr, 'user');
```

What would be the best approach to this while using `Lodash`? I understand that creating a Javascript function for this would be quite simple, although my app requires this to be done quite often, so would be good to have a simple Lodash function that is accessible.

Comment: Why do you feel the need for using lodash? If performance is your concern, using vanilla js probably more transparent and easier to optimize.

Comment: How many elements (magnitude) are you expecting in arr and objs respectively? Do you "re-query" objs for every request or is it "global"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use native js method to do that.

```
var newObj = objs.filter(function(obj) {
  return arr.indexOf(obj.user) != -1
});
```

if you are using ES6 its even more simple

```
var newObj = objs.filter(obj => arr.indexOf(obj.user) != -1);
```

There is [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9m5VdR6oJAs) which explains this concept very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

As asked, here it is in lodash:

```
var newObj = _.filter(objs, function(obj) {
  return _.indexOf(arr, obj.user) !== -1;
});
```

We can debate plain js vs lodash till the cows come home, but 1) the question asks for lodash, and 2) if objs or arr are null, the plain js answers will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

With plain JS this would work:

```
var newObj = objs.filter(function(obj) {
   return arr.indexOf(obj.user) !== -1
})
```

Comment: The OP says "*…I would like to remove that object from obj.*', Whereas *filter* creates a new array. Something like *reduceRight* might suit: `objs.reduceRight(function(acc, v, i){if (acc.indexOf(v.user) != -1) objs.splice(i, 1); return acc}, arr)`. But still no lodash. :-(

Comment: Right. Thanks. Would be interesting to know the whole repetitive / performance critical sequence

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with a combination of both `forEach()` and `remove()`

```
_(obj).forEach(function(value) {
    _.remove(arr, {
        user: value
    });
});
```